# How do I get the output to display two uniform boxes side by side?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write up a C++ program that will display a 12- and a 24-hour clock with the ability to change the minute, hour and second. Both clocks need to be displayed simultaneouosly, boxed in using "*", like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdy8e.png)

I'm fairly confident that the clocks themselves will operate like they are supposed to, but I can't get them to format properly.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// Function to create a string of a specified length with a specific character
string nCharString(size_t n, char c) {
    return string(n, c);
}

// Function to format a number as 2 digits, with a leading 0 if needed
string twoDigitString(unsigned int n) {
    if (n < 10) {
        return "0" + to_string(n);
    } else {
        return to_string(n);
    }
}

class TimeSim {
public:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int seconds;
};

class hour_12_format : public TimeSim {
public:
    string meridian;
    hour_12_format() {
        time_t now = time(0);
        tm* ltm = localtime(&now);
        hour = ltm->tm_hour;
        minute = ltm->tm_min;
        seconds = ltm->tm_sec;
        if (hour >= 12) {
            meridian = "P M";
            hour -= 12;
        } else
            meridian = "A M";
    }

    void add_hour(int h) {
        hour += h;
        if (hour > 12) {
            hour -= 12;
            if (meridian == "A M") {
                meridian = "P M";
            } else if (meridian == "P M") {
                meridian = "A M";
            }
        }
    }

    void add_minute(int min) {
        minute += min;
        if (minute >= 60) {
            int h = minute / 60;
            minute -= 60 * h;
            add_hour(h);
        }
    }

    void add_seconds(int sec) {
        seconds += sec;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            int m = seconds / 60;
            seconds -= 60 * m;
            add_minute(m);
        }
    }
};

class hour_24_format : public TimeSim {
public:
    hour_24_format() {
        time_t now = time(0);
        tm* ltm = localtime(&now);
        hour = ltm->tm_hour;
        minute = ltm->tm_min;
        seconds = ltm->tm_sec;
    }

    void add_hour(int h) {
        hour += h;
        if (hour >= 24) {
            hour -= 24;
        }
    }

    void add_minute(int min) {
        minute += min;
        if (minute >= 60) {
            int h = minute / 60;
            minute -= 60 * h;
            add_hour(h);
        }
    }

    void add_seconds(int sec) {
        seconds += sec;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            int m = seconds / 60;
            seconds -= 60 * m;
            add_minute(m);
        }
    }
};

// Function to display the 12-hour clock within a rectangle
void display12HourClock(hour_12_format c1) {
    // Display rectangle
    int rectangleWidth = 26;
    string timeStr = twoDigitString(c1.hour) + ":" + twoDigitString(c1.minute) + ":" + twoDigitString(c1.seconds) + " " + c1.meridian;
    int padding = (rectangleWidth - timeStr.length()) / 2;

    cout << nCharString(rectangleWidth, '*') << endl;
    cout << "*   12-Hour Clock: " << nCharString(padding, ' ') << timeStr << nCharString(padding, ' ') << "   *\n";
    cout << nCharString(rectangleWidth, '*') << endl;
}

// Function to display the 24-hour clock within a rectangle
void display24HourClock(hour_24_format c2) {
    // Display rectangle
    int rectangleWidth = 26;
    string timeStr = twoDigitString(c2.hour) + ":" + twoDigitString(c2.minute) + ":" + twoDigitString(c2.seconds);
    int padding = (rectangleWidth - timeStr.length()) / 2;

    cout << nCharString(rectangleWidth, '*') << endl;
    cout << "*   24-Hour Clock: " << nCharString(padding, ' ') << timeStr << nCharString(padding, ' ') << "   *\n";
    cout << nCharString(rectangleWidth, '*') << endl;
}

int main() {
    hour_12_format c1;
    hour_24_format c2;
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 4) {
        display12HourClock(c1);
        display24HourClock(c2);

        cout << "\n\n*************************\n";
        cout << "* 1 - Add One Hour\t*\n";
        cout << "* 2 - Add One Minute\t*\n";
        cout << "* 3 - Add One Second\t*\n";
        cout << "* 4 - Exit Program\t*\n";
        cout << "*************************\n";

        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            c1.add_hour(1);
            c2.add_hour(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            c1.add_minute(1);
            c2.add_minute(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            c1.add_seconds(1);
            c2.add_seconds(1);
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Enter Correct Choice!!\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is what my output looks like:

```
**************************
*   12-Hour Clock:        08:23:55 P M          *
**************************
**************************
*   24-Hour Clock:          20:23:55            *
**************************


*************************
* 1 - Add One Hour  *
* 2 - Add One Minute    *
* 3 - Add One Second    *
* 4 - Exit Program  *
*************************
```

I've tried tweaking each individual line with no luck, and can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Both `displayXXHourClock` functions must be merged to draw both clocks at once.

Comment: Calculating the time and formatting the output are distinct issues. Your code would be more focused on the formatting question if you reduced it to just the formatting. (Example code typically should **not** be the full program.) Skip the menu, and just draw one rectangle. Skip the time calculation and just hardcode (for the 12-hour clock) `string timeStr = "08:23:55 P M";`. Keep it simple and focused, with as little extraneous processing as needed to reproduce the formatting issue.

Comment: I'd advise another helper function to center text in a string with border and padding. Saves some typing and avoids code duplication. Seemed like a fun exercise so I made a version here https://godbolt.org/z/59qPzMEEW that might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the clocks to print on one line? Or in two like in the image you linked?

For one line, without the large whitespace: Currently, you calculate the `padding` without taking the "label" (`12-Hour Clock` or `24-Hour Clock`) into account.

Just the string is 14 characters + 3 left-sided whitespaces + 1 for the border, that leaves `padding = (rectangleWidth - timeStr.length() - 18) / 2`.

For example:

```cpp
void display12HourClock(hour_12_format c1) {
    // Display rectangle
    int rectangleWidth = 38;
    string timeStr = twoDigitString(c1.hour) + ":" + twoDigitString(c1.minute) + ":" + twoDigitString(c1.seconds) + " " + c1.meridian;
    int padding = (rectangleWidth - timeStr.length() - 18) / 2;
    cout << nCharString(rectangleWidth, '*') << endl;
    cout << "* 12-Hour Clock: " << nCharString(padding, ' ') << timeStr << nCharString(padding, ' ') << "*\n";
    cout << nCharString(rectangleWidth, '*') << endl;
}
```

leads to

```
**************************************
* 12-Hour Clock:     09:53:01 P M    *
**************************************
```

Note that I also removed the trailing whitespace to the line ending `*`.

The same approach should solve the menu display, that means make sure, that your whitespace count checks out.

Comment: would this work to do the two squares like the image linked?

Comment: In principle, yes. Like the other comment mentioned, it would require to combine the printing of the two clocks. Basically a string that consists of `line from clock 1` + `small padding` + `line from clock 2`. Maybe you could fix the box width first and calculate the needed paddings from there.